# Project Root in Java Including .dll

Tags: java, eclipse, jmyron

Hey I'm running Eclipse and I'm making a project that uses JMyron and apparently I need to copy a .dll to the root of my project... what is that and how do I do it in Eclipse (I'm a noob).

Note... I also have to add a .jar to my classpath

Comment: No but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990903/standalone-video-chat-application-java suggests if I want to export a JMyron project I need to include a .dll

Comment: Did you add the JAR file as a reference in eclipse or create a lib folder and copy it there, then add it to your build path (Right click on JAR - > Add to Build Path)

Comment: All I've done so far, is I right clicked on the project, hit build path -> configure build path -> Add External JARs and added the JMyron.jar ...I don't really know what to do about the .dll's yet

Comment: I don't know why you would use a DLL with Java. The JAR should suffice. I am not familiar with JMyron but usually the DLL should reside in like the program directory. What happens when you reference JMyron methods and try to use it?

Comment: Wait what's a program directory? And for now when I try to access a JMyron object in my code I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JMyron in java.library.path

Comment: Like C:\Program Files\Application_or_Company Name. Did you add the JAR as a reference?

Comment: It's added as a Referenced Library. Also I checked the line of code from the JMyron.jar that gave me the error which is
        // Ensure native JNI library is loaded
        System.loadLibrary("JMyron");

Comment: what happens if you put the DLL in your bin or lib dir?

Comment: How do I do that (total noob here)

Comment: Go to the workspace directory for your project, create a sub folder in your project folder called lib (it should already exist with your JAR file and put the DLL there).

Comment: I went to the workspace and there was no lib folder only a bin, so I tried putting the .dll in the bin and also created a folder called lib and put them in there but the same error is happening. I'm going to restart my computer because I had the same problem with xuggler and restarting helped.

Comment: Okay I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: @CodeMonkey let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2287/discussion-between-tyler-petrochko-and-code-monkey)